# Cordova read external archive and play

Tags: android, file, cordova, playback

I am creating an app with cordova for android using plugin file-transfer. The download is going to a certain folder but I can't read the file despite indicating the correct path follows the code

```
var uri = encodeURI(mypage);
           var fileURL =  cordova.file.externalDataDirectory + "teste.ogg";

           fileTransfer.download(
              uri, fileURL, function(entry) {
                    console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
                  $("#audio-teste").attr('src',fileURL)
                  /*--codigo de teste--*/
            var meuFile = cordova.file.externalDataDirectory;
                  resolveLocalFileSystemURL(meuFile, function(entry) {
                      
                      var readerN = fileSystem.createReader();
                      readerN.readEntries(
                          function (entry) {
                              var arrayN =[];
                        for(var i="0"; i < entry.length; ++i){
                            var entradaN = entry[i].name;
                            arrayN.push(entradaN);
                            //console.log(array);
                            console.log('teste aq' + arrayN);
                        }
                          }
                      )
                      //console.log(entry);
                  });
            
                  /*----*/
                  
              },

              function(error) {
                 console.log("download error source " + error.source);
                 console.log("download error target " + error.target);
                 console.log("download error code" + error.code);
              },

              false, {
                 headers: {
                    "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
                 }
              }
           );
          
          /*----*/
```

Comment: Please add what error are you getting to the question.

Comment: what happens is that the program downloads correctly from the server and saves it in the path file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/br.com.dreamsourcerstudios.www/files/teste.ogg in my html but click event dont play this audio

Answer (score 0):

The cordova plugin `cordova-plugin-file-transfer` is [due to be deprecated](https://cordova.apache.org/blog/2017/10/18/from-filetransfer-to-xhr2.html) and its latest [npm version fails on iOS](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/issues/297).

Therefore these two working functions are purely based on vanilla JS, and thus no need to use extra plugins, besides the standard plugin `cordova-plugin-file`. Therefore this is compatible with any platform.

https://gist.github.com/jfoclpf/07e52f6bdf9c967449c4bc06af44c94a

I paste here for your convenience:

```js
// for different types of cordovaFileSystem check here: 
// https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file/#where-to-store-files
// or simply type in the console `console.log(cordova.file)`
function downloadFileToDevice (fileurl, filename, cordovaFileSystem, callback) {
  var onerror = (err) => {
    console.error(`Error downloading from ${fileurl} to cordovaFileSystem ${cordovaFileSystem}`, 
    err, new Error(err))
    if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(Error(err)) }
  }

  var blob = null
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open('GET', fileurl)
  xhr.responseType = 'blob' // force the HTTP response, response-type header to be blob
  xhr.onload = () => {
    blob = xhr.response // xhr.response is now a blob object
    var DataBlob = blob
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordovaFileSystem, (dirEntry) => {
      const sanitizedFilename = filename.replace(/[^a-z0-9\.]/gi, '_').toLowerCase() // sanitize filename
      dirEntry.getFile(sanitizedFilename, { create: true }, (file) => {
        file.createWriter((fileWriter) => {
          fileWriter.write(DataBlob)
          if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback(null, cordovaFileSystem + sanitizedFilename) }
        }, (err) => { console.error('Error on file.createWriter'); onerror(err) })
      }, (err) => { console.error('Error on dirEntry.getFile'); onerror(err) })
    }, (err) => { console.error('Error on resolveLocalFileSystemURL'); onerror(err) })
  }
  xhr.onerror = (err) => { console.error('Error on XMLHttpRequest'); onerror(err) }
  xhr.send()
}
```

An example for downloading a file

```js
downloadFileToDevice('https://example.com/img.jpg',
  'myImg.jpg', 
  cordova.file.cacheDirectory,
  (err, localFilePath) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('An error occured downloading file:', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Download file with success: ' + localFilePath)
    }
})
```

Can you try with this? I tried and it works like a charm